# Background xml not working

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I have buttons and i want to set background xml for them, and when a user press any button i want to change its background , i work like this

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:text="@string/b_cancel" />
```

#### button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

#### button_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <padding android:top="10dip"
        android:bottom="10dip"/>



    <!-- Gradient Bg for listrow -->
    <gradient
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#808080" />
</shape>
```

#### button_bg_hover.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dip"
        android:top="10dip" />

    <!-- Gradient Bg for Button -->
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#FF0000"
        android:startColor="#808080" />

</animation-list>
```

it works good as a background but when i press the button it becomes all white, inspire of my `button_bg_hover` , why pelase? what is the correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be the misplaced -tag, change the line

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  ..... 
</animation-list>
```

to

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  .....
</shape>
```

Comment: i put it at end and still the white background appears

Comment: maybe the animation-list tag is misplaced and it should be shape

Comment: i miss to put `shape` , i will accept yoru ansewr, and please is this a good way to put padding in the background ? because when i remove it the buttons become so small

Comment: depends what you mean by background, I usually declare my padding on the button itself. But i'm not sure if there is a difference